# ComboBox not passing Selected Text to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox

I have a ComboBox in a WinForm that I'm developing. When the selection on the ComboBox is changed, the Form resets the `ProjectManager` that it has, and retrieves it from a Dictionary, using the PM's name as the Key.

The ComboBox should be just passing the name to the Dictionary, but instead it's passing something completely different

The `frm_About_PM` Code:

```
public partial class frm_About_PM : Form
    {

        private string _Name;
        private ProjectManager _Manager;
        private Dictionary<string, Project> _Projects;
        private Dictionary<string, ProjectManager> _OtherManagers;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }

            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }

        public frm_About_PM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public frm_About_PM(string Name)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Name = Name;
            lbl_PM_Name.Text = "Statistics - " + _Name;
        }

        public frm_About_PM(ProjectManager projectManager)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Manager = projectManager;
            _Name = _Manager.Name;
            InitiateCharts();
        }

        public frm_About_PM(ProjectManager projectManager, Dictionary<string, ProjectManager> OtherManagers)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Manager = projectManager;
            _Name = _Manager.Name;
            _OtherManagers = OtherManagers;

            //Load the ComboBox
            if ((_OtherManagers.Count > 0) || (_OtherManagers != null))
            {
                cmbo_ManagerSelect.DataSource = new BindingSource(_OtherManagers,null);
                cmbo_ManagerSelect.DisplayMember = "Key";
                cmbo_ManagerSelect.ValueMember = "Value";
            }

            InitiateCharts();
        }

        private void InitiateCharts()
        {
            lbl_PM_Name.Text = "Statistics - " + _Name + ":: " + _Manager.ProjectCount + " Projects";

            Dictionary<string, double> BudgetValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            Dictionary<string, double> ActualValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            Dictionary<string, DateTime> StartDateValues = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
            Dictionary<string, DateTime> EndDateValues = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
            Dictionary<string, double> CompletionValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            Dictionary<string, double> DurationValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();

            //Load the Chart
            foreach (Project P in _Manager.ProjectList.Values)
            {
                TimeSpan Duration = P.PlannedEnd - P.PlannedStart;
                BudgetValues.Add(P.ProjectNumber, P.BudgetCost);
                ActualValues.Add(P.ProjectNumber, P.ActualCost);
                StartDateValues.Add(P.ProjectNumber, P.PlannedStart);
                EndDateValues.Add(P.ProjectNumber, P.PlannedStart.Subtract(Duration));
                CompletionValues.Add(P.ProjectNumber, P.PercentComplete);
                DurationValues.Add(P.ProjectNumber, Duration.TotalDays);

            }

            chart_Projects.Series["Budget"].Points.DataBindXY(BudgetValues.Keys.ToArray(), BudgetValues.Values.ToArray());
            chart_Projects.Series["Actual"].Points.DataBindXY(ActualValues.Keys.ToArray(), ActualValues.Values.ToArray());
            chart_Completion.Series["Completion"].Points.DataBindXY(CompletionValues.Keys.ToArray(), CompletionValues.Values.ToArray());
            chart_Dates.Series["Start Fill"].Points.DataBindXY(StartDateValues.Keys.ToArray(), StartDateValues.Values.ToArray());
            chart_Dates.Series["Duration"].Points.DataBindXY(DurationValues.Keys.ToArray(), DurationValues.Values.ToArray());
            chart_Dates.ChartAreas["Dates"].AxisY.Minimum = _Manager.EarliestStart.ToOADate();
            chart_Dates.ChartAreas["Dates"].AxisY.Maximum = _Manager.LatestEnd.ToOADate();
            chart_Dates.ChartAreas["Dates"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart_Projects.ChartAreas["BudgetChart"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        }

        private void cmbo_ManagerSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("Manager Name is: '{0}'", cmbo_ManagerSelect.Text);
            _Manager = Globals.PMO_Workbook.Controller.Managers[cmbo_ManagerSelect.SelectedText];

            _Name = _Manager.Name;
            InitiateCharts();
        }
    }
```

The Output I'm getting from the last `Debug.Print` statement is this:

`Manager Name is: '[John Snow, PMO_KPAT_Dashboard.Classes.ProjectManager]'`

But it should just be passing `John Snow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combobox element is `KeyValuePair<string,ProjectManager>`, so it the output you get is proper one. What you need to have is `Key` property of `SelectedItem`, which you can achieve this way:

```
Debug.Print("Manager Name is: '{0}'", ((KeyValuePair<string,ProjectManager>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Key);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Now I have a new problem: how can I stop the SelectedIndexChanged event from triggering when I load the Binding to the ComboBox?

Comment: Nevermind. Got that part. Just removed the event handler. Thanks again!